# How fast way transfer table data to anyther table between difference Database system?

Tags: c#, database

I have two database system ,oracle and sql server. tableA have million rows data in Oracle, tableB no data in Sql server,Now I want use c# copy tableA data transfer to tableB, 
I need answer , have any idea can tell me??

Thanks sir !

Comment: Please post the code you have tried, and any errors you might be receiving.

Comment: Use ETL package such as SSIS;